# Высота в flexbox

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток!
Учусь верстать на flexbox'ах и столкнулся с проблемой.. Хотел спросить, возможно ли сделать так как на примере:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, возможно.
Нужно одну колонку сделать родительской для 4 элементов, вот пример:

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.col-6 {
  border-color: red;
  flex-basis: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-6">
    1 колонка
  </div>
  <div class="col-6 row">
    <div class="col-6">
      2.1 колонка
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      2.2 колонка
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      2.3 колонка
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      2.4 колонка
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

P.S. стили, думаю, настроишь сам:)

Comment: Большое спасибо!)
Но есть ещё одно НО:
Например, у меня есть секция `Услуги`,  и мне надо вывести их из админки, при этом первый элемент будет как на картинке, такое возможно? Использовать nth-child или просто в html выделить отдельный `<div>`, а остальные из админки.. как думаешь?

Comment: @Виталий ты можешь для удобства написать еще один класс для обозначения главного элемента(который обозначен самым левым на картинке, как я понял). Вложенность элементов выбираешь ты сам, поэтому выбор за тобой. Можно настроить, чтобы высота подбиралась автоматически под размер правых "маленьких" колонок. Тут смотря что тебе нужно.

Comment: 4 правых элемента фиксированой высоты, левый (большой) будет подстраиваться под правую часть. Как-то так :)
Как  с этим быть?

Comment: height: calc(2 * `высота правых столбцов`) - если высота фиксированная

Comment: Ну понятно, розберусь. Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

Хотя вопрос про flexbox, возможно будет также интересно решение на [css grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout):

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 70px 70px / 100px 100px 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.left {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 3 / 2;
}

.cell {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="cell left"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
  <div class="cell"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Да, за grid я знаю эту тему.. но grid пока сыроват. Страшно использовать его. Но спасибо за ответ)